# It's possible to use an old Gtk2 widget in a Gtk3 application?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I'm developing a new interface, but it depend from a custom widget which only work with Gtk2.

There are a way to use both versions, or I will must rewrite my app using Gtk2?

Comment: Could you  give us more information about that widget, if you are allowed to?

Comment: The widget is part of ZBar barcode reader, avaliable [here](http://zbar.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/zbar/zbar/file/83d7d5631458/test/test_pygtk.py), thats works fine with Gtk2, but only raise SEGFAULT with Gtk3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the widget, but, a single widget shouldn't be too hard to port. Most of the time porting is relatively easy. They've also been working on a compatibility module which enables some of the older syntax to work with GTK 3. Check out https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject/IntrospectionPorting

I ported a few of my old applications by doing a few search/replace (things like gtk. becomes Gtk., ICON_SIZE_MENU becomes IconSize.MENU, etc.) and minor tweaks.

Ideally you would continue your app in GTK 3 and help them port their widget to the new API. You're not going to want to be using GTK 2 forever.

Comment: The widget was written in C, and the author, apparently, don't work in it anymore.